# Is there a way to shorten the is/as construct?

Tags: delphi

I'd like to shorten the following code:

```
procedure TAddInModule.FinanBladCalculate(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Sender is TExcelWorksheet) then begin
    (Sender as TExcelWorksheet).Tag:= TagCalculationDone;
    // or
    TExcelWorksheet(Sender).Tag:= TagCalculationDone;
  end
  else {do nothing}
end;
```

I do a lot of this is/as checking, just to be on the safe side.
However this is a lot of typing, just to do a safe-cast.

Is there a way to shorten this and achieve the same result? 
I was thinking of using a generic solution using records and operator overloading.

The following code works:

```
program Project41;
{$APPTYPE CONSOLE} 
uses
  System.SysUtils,VCL.Forms;

type
  AsIs<T: class> = record
    Data: T;
    class operator Implicit(const a: TObject): AsIs<T>;
    function OK: boolean;
  end;

function AsIs<T>.OK: boolean;
begin
  Result:= Assigned(Data);
end;

class operator AsIs<T>.Implicit(const a: TObject): AsIs<T>;
begin
  if a is T then Result.Data:= T(a)
  else Result.Data:= nil;
end;

procedure Demonstrate(Sender: TObject);
var
  Test: AsIs<TApplication>;
begin //Something silly to demonstrate
  Test:= Sender;
  if Test.OK then Test.Data.HandleMessage;
end;

begin 
  Demonstrate(Application);
end.
```

Is there a way to make it even shorter?
Something like:

```
  Test(App).Data.HandleMessage;
  //or even
  Test(App).HandleMessage;
```

Comment: Do you really need the `is`? Very often you can go straight to the `as`. What do you mean by "to be on the safe side"? In the example you give, isn't it reasonable to assume that `Sender` is `TExcelWorksheet`. In my opinion your proposed cure is worse than the disease. Programming is not about reducing the amount of key presses of the programmer. It is by and large all about making life easier for the reader of the code. Usually yourself.  Once a day or two has passed, who knows what state your memory is in?! So simple and clear is invariably best.

Comment: The `as` will generate an exception if the object `is` not of the required type. I don't want to generate exceptions. Yes in the above example it is safe to assume.

Comment: That's my point. When it is safe to assume, do so. In that case you do want an exception in case your assumption is wrong. That's preferable to a silent failure. But my main point is that I think (my opinion) that all you can hope to achieve here is add complexity to your code for negligible benefit.

Comment: make `OK` an `inline` function imho

Comment: @Arioch'The How does that help conciseness which is what Johan asked about?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan would it be the answer - i'd put it to answers not tocomments.  However binary code probably would be more laconic indeed

Comment: with the current implementation you can write if  AsIs<TApplication>(Sender).o then ....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is an opinion, that a code should separate GUI and the logic, like in MVC pattern, so the event handlers should not contain any actual work but merely route user's activity to the actual business-logic implementers, like

```
procedure TAddInModule.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  if (Sender is TExcelWorksheet) then 
     FinanBladCalculate(TExcelWorksheet(Sender));
end;

procedure TAddInModule.FinanBladCalculate(Sheet: TExcelWorksheet);
begin
  Sheet.Tag:= TagCalculationDone;
  ...
  ...
  ...
end;
```

That way later many more events would be able to call the `FinanBladCalculate` with the real workload centralized and contained there (like menus, hotkeys, gestures, etc).

This pattern perhaps can use that record to an extent

```
procedure TAddInModule.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FinanBladCalculate(Sender);
end;

procedure TAddInModule.MenuItem1Click(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FinanBladCalculate(Sender);
end;

procedure TAddInModule.CheckBox1Check(Sender: TObject);
begin
  FinanBladCalculate(Sender);
end;

....

procedure TAddInModule.FinanBladCalculate(const Sheet: AsIs<TExcelWorksheet>);
begin
  if Sheet.Data = nil then exit;

  Sheet.Data.Tag:= TagCalculationDone;
  ...
  ...
  ...
end;
```

If you have many GUI elements that can initiate some work and have different event handlers, that might make sense.

Comment: kind of sad that this limited answer is the winner, so no better, more general-use answers were made :-(

Answer (score 6):

Use **absolute**.  You can still exercise the caution needed to ensure type safety, but **absolute** allows you to use *declarative* typecasting vs inline typecasting or **as** with its implicit, redundant **is** check (redundant if you are checking type *explicitly* yourself):

```
var
  excel: TExcelWorksheet absolute aSender;
begin
  if aSender is TExcelWorksheet then
  begin
    excel.Tag := TagCalculationDone;
  end;
end;
```

The **absolute** declaration makes **excel** a typed-synonym for the memory address referenced in the declaration.  i.e. there is no additional local variable and no code required to perform the typecast to assign a value to that variable.  Rather **excel** is just another way of accessing the value of **aSender**.

You can have as many typed-synonyms to the same address as you may need.  So if **aSender** could also be a **TWordDocument** (or whatever):

```
var
  excel: TExcelWorksheet absolute aSender;
  word: TWordDocument absolute aSender;
begin
  if aSender is TExcelWorksheet then
  begin
    excel.Tag := TagCalculationDone;
  end
  else if aSender is TWordDocument then
  begin
    word.Tag := TagFieldsUpdated;  // Or whatever
  end;
end;
```

The same technique can be used to create such synonyms for local variables as well as parameters.

Comment: Oh boy. I answered this before but it seems nobody likes me here :'(. I only got downvotes

Comment: That is not any shorter than the classic `is` check followed by a hardcast.

Comment: I'd make it as `if (* aSender *) excel is TExcelWorksheet then ...` - to keep centralization better. Then formal function parameter can be renamed or maybe the "excel" variable re-wired to some other variable, but the code would remain consistent

Comment: OTOH, while I generally agree with "absolute" usage here, I find this answer totally ignoring `AsIs<C>` record of the topicstarter. And he asked not about the best practices of typecasting, but about using his specific generic datatype

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound you made a similar but a different answer. I supported you on using "absolute" but me and other commenters sharply criticized your removing of `X is Y` safety check. That was a crucial difference in our eyes, while you kept telling type checking is not relevant and is not needed

Comment: @StefanGlienke with a single `excel.tag := ...` oneliner - it is not. But it is assumed this stub would be expanded to the real working smple, where the variable would be used dozen of times. I explicitly hinted at that in my answer, but honestly, I think it is clear when there is one use of the variable, there may later come ten more  of them. Also by centralizing typecasts `absolute` adds to type safety for later refactorings: you cannot miss one or two places to substitute a new type or a new var name, if you only have it in a single place in the function header

Comment: @Arioch'The If I remember correctly I added a piece of code demonstranting how to perform the type check. As I said in my answer, there is cases where one don't need type check.

Comment: @Arioch'The Never Mind. Next time, I will remember this and I'll stay on my nescience and don't waste efforts typing.

Comment: @Arioch - the answer "shortens" the "is .. as" construct by eliminating the "as" part.  The OP was not asking for comments on his generic implementation (SO is not a forum for such general discussions/requests) but offered that as what they had come up with as a way of "shortening" the "is .. as" themselves.  The use of type checking + absolute avoids a lot of the hidden overhead that any generic based approach necessarily entails, achieving conciseness without sacrificing efficiency.

Comment: @EProgrammerNotFound - I saw your answer and would have undeleted it if I could (or could see how).  As others have noted, the downvotes were due to the lack of emphasis on type safety, but imho downvoting was unwarranted and this could and should have been addressed in comments on the answer (and easily fixed with a revision to the answer itself).  As I say, I would have restored your answer if I could, but since I couldn't I decided to re-post it myself.  No offense intended (far from it - I thought it was an answer worth keeping!).

Comment: @Stefan - it is shorter (and safer) than *repeated* hard type-casting.  Shorter for obvious reasons and *safer* because the more times you have to do something the more opportunity there is to make a mistake in the doing.

Comment: There would not be repeated hard casting. There would be a local variable. It wouldn't be discernibly shorter. You'd avoid the local var but introduce `absolute`. To me this feels worse than the simple approach.

Comment: @David - There would be repeated casting without a local variable (which Stefan did not mention, btw).  Even a local var requires additional memory (the local var) and additional code (a required, explicit typecast assignment to that variable, which could easily be missed leading to an uninitialised variable and possible Heisenbug).  Whilst my preference for **absolute** is not based on code/memory use, it does seem rather odd to consider it less simple than an approach which requires *more* code, *more* memory (albeit trivial in quantity) and creates *more* potential for error.  ymmv.

Comment: More code and more memory are not problems here.  I don't really see that there is more potential for error.

Comment: You see it your way, I see it mine.  I offer one approach you personally wouldn't use.  We all get to consider the different approaches and choose the one that's right for us.  Why not post your "simple" answer if you think it preferable/superior ?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan mistypings and refactorings, as usual. Introducing "unbound" variable, you need to write an extra code to initialize it and to do a typecast in that initializing assignment. That opens the potential to specify different types or different var-names in that extra code today or tomorrow. Every extra code brings an extra risk of introducing bugs.
I agree that this extra risk is rather small in this case, so I would not protest the "extra var" approach. Still I feel that "absolute" approach is a bit more efficient in every sense.